pgAdmin4 no longer shows Login Dialog (page)
I no longer see a Login dialog in PgAdmin4 version 8.7.  How am I supposed to login different users without having to go to the properties of the database and change the login user and password?
I've looked through the config.py file and made changes to use LDAP authentication first and internal second.  I use a bind account for the LDAP, and all of the fun stuff.
The config.py file has a lot more in the configuration, but these are the parameters that I can see need to be configured.  Aside from that, I do not see anywhere to enable or disable the login dialog.
# Add any configuration changes to this file. 
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['ldap','internal']
LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://<ip_address:port>'
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = 'cn'
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'dc=domain,dc=com'
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN = 'ou=ldap,dc=domain,dc=com'
LDAP_BIND_USER = '<bind_account>'
LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ''

Each time I launch the PgAdmin4 application it goes right into the GUI and when connecting to the Database, it prompts for the password of the configured admin account; I have store password disabled.
I tried to configure the config_local.py and the config.py files in accordance with the instructions from
PgAdmin - Login Page
and
PgAdmin - Enabling LDAP Authentication
I have already set roles for the different users to Login.
My rea goal is to be able to launch PgAdmin4 from the command line, but apparently they disabled that and all I'm able to do is run the command as follows.  Unfortunately it just skips authentication altogether and simply launches the app to dashboard.
pgadmin4 > psql.exe "host=<hostname> port=<port> dbname=postgres "user=<user> sslmode=prefer connect_timeout=10"

Which I am sure is wrong ...
I've also read other Stack Overflow articles, but I cannot seem to find one that would explain why this is.
This is a Windows deployment of PgAdmin4, and PostgreSQL server is also deployed on a Windows Server.

Is your issue fixed? Can you share screenshots?

I'm sorry, but the issue is not fixed. I moved beyond that for now. I would still like to know a solution, though.
